# finding the type of encoding

Tags: python, character-encoding

I was wondering if we can find out the type of encoding used for an encoded string? Or at least find out if a given entity or word is a string or bytes in python3.x.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if it's string or bytes is simple:

```
isinstance(x, str)
```

vs

```
isinstance(x, bytes)
```

Once you have determined that it is bytes, then you can, as Daniel said in his answer use [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to let it guess what encoding it is. This is highly unreliable on short texts, though, but on longer ones it works fine.

Comment: Not sure how this test is supposed to work, but I think the following shows it doesn't work:
>>> type (x)
<type 'str'>
>>> isinstance (x,bytes)
True
>>> isinstance (x,str)
True

Comment: @kasterma: That's because under Python 2, str and bytes are the same type. This is not the case in Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend the [`chardet`](http://chardet.feedparser.org/) library.  It's based off of [some work from Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html) and seems to meet your need.

[Usage is pretty easy](http://chardet.feedparser.org/docs/usage.html#example.basic.detect):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> rawdata = urllib.urlopen('http://yahoo.co.jp/').read()
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(rawdata)
{'encoding': 'EUC-JP', 'confidence': 0.99}
```

And there are more complex use-cases that are covered on that page as well, but at the core you can simply pass in a string and have it return a set of potential encodings along with their confidences in that guess.